# Quasi-isomorphisms of P-algebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, operads

In the paper "Homotopy algebras are homotopy algebras" from Markl a notion of strong homotopy morphism between strong homotopy P-algebras is defined. The author restricts to the case where $P(0) = 0$, $P(1) = \mathbb{K}$ (with $\mathbb{K}$ a characteristic zero field), and $P$ has trivial differential, but the notion is still definable for a general operad.

In the paper "Deformation theory of representations of prop(erads) I" from Vallette and Merkulov it is proven (Proposition 56) that if $P$ is a Koszul operad then Merkulov's definition coincides with the well-known definition of $\infty$-morphism between $\infty$-operads (see Loday and Vallete's book "Algebraic Operads"). This means that, if $A$ and $B$ are two $P$-algebras, a strong homotopy quasi-isomorphism $A \to B$ (meaning that the underlying map of such a strong homotopy morphism is a quasi-isomorphism) is equivalent to the existence of a chain of $P$-algebra morphisms $A \to \bullet \leftarrow \cdots \to B$ inducing an isomorphism on homology.

I was wondering if this remains true in the general case, not only when $P$ is not Koszul, but also in those cases where the differential $d_P$ is not necessarily trivial, and $P(1)$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{K}$.